# SQL Server variable give me singleton error

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a `XML` column in a table with the following structure

```
<md xmlns="http://www.intellipayment.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <dist>
    <ml>
      <S>368.72</S>
      <src>26249201</src>
      <t>26249202</t>
    </ml>
    <ml>
    ....
    </ml>
  </dist>
</md>
```

I would like to select all src and perform operation one by one.

So my SQL statement is :

```
while @i <= @xmlCount
begin
    select 
        @CurrentSrc = AssignmentDistribution.value('(/*:md/*:dist/*:ml/*:src/text())[sql:variable("@i")]', 'varchar(50)')
    from 
        table 
    where 
        id = 1234

    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

I get this error:

> XQuery [autodeals.AssignmentDistribution.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

However, if I replace the SQL variable with a static number 1, 2,3,4 ..... it will show me the result correctly.

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's possibly because [`sql:variable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) returns `xdt:anyAtomicType`, I'm not sure. But this is one possible alternative, by using `query()` first, which enforce no limitation of returning only singleton, and then convert the return value to `varchar(50)` using `value()` function :

```
select @CurrentSrc = AssignmentDistribution
                         .query('(/*:md/*:dist/*:ml/*:src/text())[sql:variable("@i")]')
                         .value('.', 'varchar(50)')
FROM table where id = 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use this approach with the `.nodes()` call, you don't need to manually do any looping - you get your `src` values as a nice, relational data set and you can operate on them.....

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.intellipayment.com'),
SrcFromXml AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Src = XC.value('(src)[1]', 'int')
    FROM
        table 
    CROSS APPLY
        AssignmentDistribution.nodes('/md/dist/ml') AS XT(XC)
)
SELECT *
FROM SrcFromXml
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I know this solution, but I am more interested for why it gives me an error.

Comment: @KennethLam: one **big** reason is that you completely ignore the **XML namespace** on the document and you try to select as if there is no XML namespace in play.

Comment: the name space is not the problem.  I figure out how to select with the sql variable without specfying the namespace.